# Can coins count as raw materials for Fabricate?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195779/23547) asks how a party can move 10,000 pounds of gold coins quickly, to remove them from a treasure vault before the Waterdeep authorities arrive and demand their share.

Currently three answers ([here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/195789/23547), [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/195787/23547), and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/195811/23547)) and a comment on a fourth [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/195785/23547) from the [author](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28402/carcer) of one of the three answers, suggest using the spell *[Fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate)* to turn the coins into solid ingots, the better to count as a single object for the application of spells like *Reduce*.  So far, no one has expressed any objection to using the spell like that.

Because my objection is longish, and rather than start a comment dialog that will be moved into chat on three separate answers, it seemed better to ask this as a separate question.  **Am I misunderstanding the *Fabricate* spell; can finished coins actually be used as the raw materials for ingots?**

Fabricate says:

> You convert raw materials into products of the same material. For example, you can fabricate a wooden bridge from a clump of trees, a rope from a patch of hemp, and clothes from flax or wool.

That seems pretty straightforward to me - 'raw materials' in, 'products' of those raw materials out.  The examples make sense - a clump of trees is used to make a bridge, a patch of hemp is used to make a rope, and flax or wool are used to make clothes.

But all the answers on the linked question assume that you can use the spell to turn coins into gold ingots; that is, that coins are somehow 'raw materials' that are used to make the finished 'product' of an ingot.

Now, I don't doubt that you *could* melt down coins and use them to make an ingot, or even that people have actually done that at some point.  But that doesn't seem like the normal production of finished goods that the spell assumes, whereby the product is much more highly processed than the raw materials.  A coin, as I see it, is hardly a 'raw material'.  Since 5e coins are apparently pure gold, one must first mine the ore, extract the gold, purify it, and then hammer it into sheets that are just the correct thickness to be cut into coins.  If they are to be actual coins, and not just circular pieces of gold, they then need to be [minted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coining_(mint)#Medieval_coin_dies), or have figures, words, and numbers impressed on them with hand-crafted and possibly engraved dies.  This level of processing can hardly result in what I would call 'raw materials', and while a solid gold ingot has been subjected to some of the same processing, it seems like objectively less.

For full context, the DM asking the question has made this heist a central theme of their campaign, and it appears that they want the players to succeed, but also to have to work over many sessions to come up with a functional plan that challenges their resources and creativity.  If a DM *wants* the spell *Fabricate* to work in such a way to serve their greater campaign narrative, then good on them.  I am not asking whether a DM *should* allow this or the merits of doing so.

It doesn't seem to me like this is what the spell, RAW, actually does, and *that* is what I would like answers to address.

Related, but for 3.5e, [Can I use fabricate to turn gold coins into ingots worth three times as much gold?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80172/23547)

Comment: Somewhat related on [How much is a gold piece really worth?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61840/how-much-is-a-gold-piece-really-worth)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

“Raw materials” literally means only “materials used to make something else.” Anything that can be used to make something else can be considered a raw material. That is, something is a “raw material” *only* with respect to a particular *process* of creation—the finished product of one process may well be the raw materials used by another process.

Merriam–Webster, for example, [defines “raw material”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raw%20material) as

> crude *or processed* material that can be converted by manufacture, processing, or combination into a new and useful product

<sup>(*emphasis* mine)</sup>

The examples given in *[fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate)* are, themselves, somewhat illuminating. Consider that we have both “wool,” as well as “a clump of trees.” Wool requires some processing to obtain—it has to be shorn off of sheep. Meanwhile, in most cases, the “raw material” assumed for wood objects is *lumber*, that is, trees that have been cut down and sawed into more-or-less uniform pieces. Most processes wouldn’t consider still-living trees to even be raw material, as they need harvesting and processing to become lumber, the “real” raw material for most purposes.

Unless, of course, you’re operating a logging operation.

Ultimately, “raw material” is always a relative term, where the material is “raw” only in comparison to the final product. *Fabricate* uses the term in the same way: whatever you’re casting the spell on, has to be something you could use to produce what you’re trying to get out. There are no other restrictions.

And, for the record, nothing about the process of turning gold into coins does anything to them that prevents them from being used for other goldsmithing. In fact, given that coins typically come with a stamp guaranteeing a certain high and standardized level of purity, they’re a pretty *good* raw material for goldsmithing—not as convenient as an ingot carrying a similar sort of stamp, but nonetheless. If nothing else, gold coins were *often* [used as the raw material in the forging](https://www.bundesbank.de/resource/blob/607732/99668609e0d13564c8ec9920f63c40fd/mL/ancient-gold-coins-data.pdf) of *more gold coins*, because old and damaged coins were recycled into new coins.

Comment: Certainly wool is processed - it has been shorn, carded, spun, and maybe even dyed.  However, it is _less processed_ than clothes, a pattern that follows all three of the examples given.  You don't think there is any implication that the spell is only used for upcycling rather than downcycling?

Comment: @Kirt I think it would be extremely difficult to *quantify* how processed something is, and I’d point out the processing for ingots and coins just about exactly the same—purify, weigh, mold, stamp. Just different molds, really. In both cases, arguably less processing than clothes, I’d think. And ingots definitely are the typical raw material that most smiths work with. “Raw material” just means different things to different people. At any rate, I don’t really think there’s any justification for trying to split hairs of this sort with *fabricate*; I don’t think any such were intended.

Comment: @Kirt Another thing to consider: in the modern era, a major “raw material” necessary for a lot of industries—and generating many headlines today due to supply issues—is computer chips. There are a ton of standardized ICs produced by any number of suppliers that are bought off the shelf or in bulk to incorporate into commercial and hobbyist projects. An integrated circuit is an incredibly processed piece of technology, but I don’t think you could argue that *fabricate* would fail to assemble them into a circuit. I’d sooner expect it to fail if starting from sand and copper.

Comment: Historically it was actually illegal in many places to melt down coins for use for other purposes. Re-minting was a special exception to this in most such places, but in general turning gold coins into, say, jewelry, without the permission of the country (or other entity) who minted them was almost always illegal.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Fair enough, but I really don’t think *fabricate* is capable of knowing, much less enforcing, the law.

Comment: Agreed, my only point was that there may be some undesirable story consequences if it becomes known to the local authorities that the players are doing this.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn In the original question that prompted this, local authorities already would have had strong objections, since legally the coins belonged to the city and not to the players. But fair point in general.

Comment: Per [usmint.gov](https://www.usmint.gov/learn/kids/coins/fun-facts/category/penny), "Most of our coins are metal sandwiches. The outside layers are three-quarters copper and one-quarter nickel, and the "filling" is solid copper. Only nickels are one solid material—that same 75% copper/25% nickel alloy." So it is entirely possible that a "gold piece" is not pure gold. [Gold is twice as heavy](http://www.etantdonnes.com/MACHINE/TABLES/metalDensity.htm) as copper, yet all coins weigh the same for inventory sake. It's not unreasonable to think coins are plated/processed.

Comment: @KRyan I don't think you need to quantify how processed something is, but perhaps you need to qualify it - if the spell requires that the product be _more_ processed than the raw material.  I am beginning to think that there are two issues - you have convinced me that ingots are just as processed as coins and this specific example is possible. But the second issue is whether the spell _cares_ about the relative processing. What is the purpose of saying it needs _raw_ materials, as opposed to just 'You convert materials into products of the same material'?

Comment: @Kirt You have a semantic point that a DM might use to rule, however consider the ingot a statue. If gold coins could be made into a statue, then an ingot or cuboid made from the coins would simply be a *specific statue*.

Comment: @kirt possibly because natural language uses raw materials in the same way you use materials, and uses materials to mean 'cloth'. At least everyone I talk to speaks that way. Using materials might be technically correct, but 5e isn't a technical document, it uses natural language.

Comment: @MivaScott Modern coins are both made differently and made of different materials than coins were when they needed to be made from the actually precious metal that gave them value. Plating a coin makes no sense when you’re using a gold standard. Impure alloys have been used (the oldest coins we know of were electrum, an alloy of gold and silver), but then they aren’t _gold coins_, they are using some other standard.

Comment: @Kirt Because “raw material” is a common and natural way to express the idea that *fabricate* is processing the target materials to produce some other good. There is widespread acknowledgment of the idea that “raw material” is a relative term.

Comment: Even today coins are used to fabricate other things - example: [YT: How to make double sided silver Morgan, Peace dollar coin rings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4pWpU3_qNw) - no affiliation

Comment: @MivaScott When the value of a gold piece depends on it being a piece of pure gold, as opposed to modern fiat currency whose value depends on trust in the government issuing it.... if it's not actually pure gold, it's counterfeit and phony, and a) doesn't actually have the value expected and b) is going to make people upset if they find out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133987/discussion-between-akixkisu-and-kryan).

Answer (score 26):

### There Is No Rules-As-Written Answer

What you're asking for is a 5e-defined bright line categorization of "raw materials" vs "not raw materials."  But there isn't one, only three small examples from the spell itself which are not sufficient to generalize to all cases.

Failing that, 5e falls back on a tradition of "plain English reading" or "[Idiomatic English reading](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135042/18269)."  But here we also run into difficulty, because "raw material" is highly context sensitive, and no bright-line rule really exists in English; no single definition is going to do justice to the concept unless it is a contextual definition pinning itself to known concepts like the progression of unfinished goods into more and more complex goods.

You *can* insist on a definition that favors metal ores and fresh fallen tree limbs, or a definition that favors ingots and dressed timber.  I think there's a strong case to be made for a GM's right to favor one over the other, as long as it's communicated early and consistently.  But **there is simply no support in the rules as written for favoring one over the other that I can see**, on an idiomatic basis.

I, myself, would allow the use of coins, based on the following two-prong logic:

- I just really doubt that the designer intent is to consider silver ore as raw material for a silver sword, but not silver ingots, and,
- I just can't see the meaningful difference between silver ingots and silver coins, in this context.  They're just different shapes of the same stuff.  (Frankly, I would probably vanish in a puff of semiotic smoke if I tried to work through the ramifications of why a 4th level spell would care about the difference between ingots and coins.)

But I would not pretend that is a Rules-as-Written ruling.  It isn't.  It's a GM filling in the blanks because the rules are not infinitely precise ruling.

Answer (score 10):

#### Let's not quibble amount the meaning of "Raw Materials"

5e isn't SAP Enterprise Resource Planning software, where each item number is defined as raw, in-process, finished, etc. In this case, it's just a material we use to make something else. And even SAP will let us make an assembly out of multiple finished goods. 5e wasn't written by material planners, it's just regular people.

Of course, we can use "finished goods" to make other things. While the examples given use trees to make a bridge, there's nothing stopping us from using a truckload of staves to do the same thing. The spell restrictions just mean we need to use material to make material. Coins are just minimally-processed metal anyway.

**It's fine.**

Comment: That is perhaps the single most horrifying and hilarious answer I have ever seen, and it will haunt my nightmares forever.

Answer (score 3):

Every DM I've had has allowed us to use coins as raw materials. The reasoning was sound, in my opinion: we were basically buying materials by using money as the materials. This created a finite amount of materials to use and we obviously had to carefully manage how we did this or possibly go broke and starve to death. Money wasn't always hard to come by, but this made it reasonable to use as a source.

Answer (score 3):

As many have said, "raw materials" is somewhat difficult to parse out.  But take a look at the bigger picture:  What is happening here?

To make something in the mundane way, you have inputs, in the form of raw materials.  And then people would do work on the raw materials in order to eventually produce an object.  *Fabricate* essentially replaces "a bunch of people doing hard work" with "I snap my fingers".  If I could pay workmen to, eventually, produce the object I want *Fabricated*, then the spell can do it.  (The spell even explicitly references artisan's tools if you want to get fancy, further implying this link.)

In other words, I can (using the example provided) make a bridge out of some trees.  But I can't make a metal sword out of trees.  The phrase "raw materials" means that, while some degree of transformation is involved, you can't squeeze blood out of a stone.  *Fabricate* is not *True Polymorph*.

Could a bunch of people take gold coins and melt them down into ingots?  Absolutely.  Then they are "raw materials" for the purpose of this spell, at least when used to make bullion or (say) a gold statue (if you also meet the artisan's tools requirement).

In the same way, if you had the raw ingredients for, say, alchemist's fire on hand, then using *Fabricate* to make alchemist's fire seems like a perfectly reasonable use of the spell.

I would also allow someone to take old, rusty metal objects and *Fabricate* a new piece of equipment out of them, or use *Fabricate* to, say, repair a sword that had snapped in half.  Because you could hire a blacksmith to do that, *Fabricate* can do it also.  (But do note the restriction to one object per casting generally makes this a waste of a slot.)

Answer (score -3):

#### Coins are not raw materials

*Fabricate* states:

> You convert **raw materials** into products of the same material. For example, you can fabricate a wooden bridge from a clump of trees, a rope from a patch of hemp, and clothes from flax or wool.

“Raw materials” has no special definition in the context of the rules, so we understand it in its usual English definition. Borrowing from the Wikipedia article for the term, we see:

> The term raw material denotes materials in unprocessed or minimally processed states; e.g., raw latex, crude oil, cotton, coal, raw biomass, iron ore, air, logs, water, or "any product of agriculture, forestry, fishing or mineral in its natural form

This definition of raw materials is consistent with the examples given in the spell description, “clump of trees”, “patch of hemp”, “flax or wool”.

What we are looking for to use with *fabricate* are materials *in their natural form*. Coins are indisputably not the natural form of the minerals they are composed of, rather, *coins are already a final product having been manufactured from raw ore for use as currency*, so they are not eligible materials for fabrication via *fabricate*.

Comment: Odd to go to a wiki article for a definition, my search finds 'the basic material from which a product is made' and is more akin to how I am people I talk to understand it. The raw material in a ladder for example wouldn't be a tree, but wood. That might still disallow coins from working, but for different reasons.

Comment: @SeriousBri Id he more lenient with precut timber counting *because precut timber is not a final product*. It is an intermediate material that has no other purpose but to be a material for constructing other things. Coins are already a final product having reached the final form required for their intended purpose.

Comment: @SeriousBri what products are made directly from coins?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Coin collections and flat pennies.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage not much, that is why I said 'that might still disallow coins'. I don't disagree with the conclusion, just the specific definition used.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Wishes

Comment: "magic items can't be created or transmuted by this spell. " If "Magic items" specifically can't be transmuted (the raw material side) by this, it seems like that leaves "items" available.

Comment: What about coin-sized gold discs with precise weights? Those might be an easy way to transport gold as a raw material for gold-smithing smallish items. You might even stamp them with who made them. But they aren't coins -- they're special gold raw material.

Comment: Historically coins are raw materials in the "coin -> smaller coin + shavings" process

Comment: If you're bringing purpose into it how would you rule altering a stone wall? The stone has been chiselled into shape and built into the intended end product as a wall. Sounds like one of those aspects that is going to have to be the DM's call at the end of the day - enough cases of "What about..." For there to be no one size fits all answer.

Comment: I do not think coins in D&D are necessarily "money". . . They are measured units of a more valuable substance and are widely accepted in trades and bartering. A disc of elemental gold, stamped with a seal indicating the weight and relative "value" is about as raw as it gets.

Comment: @Turbo "about as raw as it gets" well no, gold ore you dug out of a mine, gold nuggets you found in the river downstream from the mine...

Comment: Coins are also the raw materials for jewlery that is made with just a little drill and rivets!

Comment: While I agree with this answer in that coins are manufactured/finished goods, not raw materials, "*Coins are indisputably not the natural form of the minerals they are composed of*" requires some caveat -- platinum, gold, silver, and copper are special cases since they are elemental metals. A gold coin should be 100% gold content, for example. Same for the other, lower coin denominations. While a gold coin in this sense, a gold coin would be about the same as a gold ingot (both need to be melted down to be worked into a finished good) it's weird b/c ingots aren't "finished goods" like coins.

Answer (score -3):

### Coins are not “raw materials” (probably)

Coins are clearly manufactured and so do not meet the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raw%20material) of raw materials in the sense that *Fabricate* uses it. They are the end product of a processing and manufacturing process and are rarely, if ever, turned into something else.

An argument could be made that they can be an input into a business and are therefore raw materials in a metaphorical sense but a) that’s not what the spell contemplates and b) you’d have to accept that a businesses’ workforce are also raw materials and therefore valid targets for the spell.

There is a question as to whether the metal gold is a valid target - except for alluvial gold, the metal is the processed form of gold bearing ore, so it’s not a “raw material”. Strictly speaking, only alluvial gold in nugget or dust form is “raw materials” because smelting it into ingots is processing it.

This is a variation of [Sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox) aka the heap problem. Human language has a category called “raw materials” which you want to have hard, clean edges so that something is clearly in the category or not in the category. However, the edges of the category are inherently and unavoidable blurry. Each DM has to draw their own line.

Let me illustrate by using something the spell actually mentions: “a wooden bridge from a clump of trees”.

- What if the trees have been felled?
- Does it matter if they were felled deliberately be lumberjacks or naturally by a storm?
- If it does, does it matter if the storm was magical?
- If it does, does it matter if the magic was a “natural” intrusion from the Plane of Air or a spell?
- Does it matter if the felled trees have had their limbs removed turning them into logs?
- Or if the logs have been turned into lumber? I means, lumber is clearly the raw material of bridge building. Wooden bridges at least.
- What if the lumber has been turned into a wagon?
- What if you disassemble the wagon, turning it back into (used) lumber? After all, second-hand lumber is the raw material for some very expensive furniture.

Where do you draw the line?

Me, well, a grove of trees is definitely ok and a pre-existing bridge definitely isn’t. (Although, an older bridge can serve as its own raw materials for a rebuild …). Everything else, I’ll decide on a case by case basis.

Comment: You end with calling a bridge raw materials, which is in direct contradiction to the rest of your answer, and even the sentence directly before it.

Comment: @SeriousBri of course. That’s the point. “Raw materials” is a fuzzy category. Bridges (and coins) can be recycled - does that make them raw materials or not?

Comment: But your headline is quite clear that they are NOT raw materials. If you are trying to say 'its unclear' then you need at least a new headline. It reads as if you wanted to say no, but slowly convinced yourself that actually they might be, and the answer ended up muddled.